# What lines <built-in>, <command-line> and from where a header it taken after simple gcc -E means?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

main.c:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

After preprocessing stage: `gcc -E main.c`

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"
int main() { return 0; }
```

I know that:

- the first numbers are line numbers of a processed file;
- the "strings" are file names;
- the numbers at the end of lines are described here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

What does other lines mean? I mean: `<built-in>`, `<command-line>` and from where `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h` is taken?

Here I found this question [GCC preprocessing, what are the built-in and command-line lines for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577259) almost "without" answers.

```
gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
```

---

**UPDATED: Explanation of `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h`**

The header file `stdc-predef.h` was hardcoded in `gcc/config/glibc-c.c` (from [git repo](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html)):

```
 26 /* Implement TARGET_C_PREINCLUDE for glibc targets.  */
 27 
 28 static const char *
 29 glibc_c_preinclude (void)
 30 {
 31   return "stdc-predef.h";
 32 }
```

It is processed in `push_command_line_include` of `gcc/c-family/c-opts.c`:

```
1534 /* Give CPP the next file given by -include, if any.  */
1535 static void
1536 push_command_line_include (void)
1537 {
1538   /* This can happen if disabled by -imacros for example.
1539      Punt so that we don't set "<command-line>" as the filename for
1540      the header.  */
1541   if (include_cursor > deferred_count)
1542     return;
1543 
1544   if (!done_preinclude)
1545     {
1546       done_preinclude = true;
1547       if (flag_hosted && std_inc && !cpp_opts->preprocessed)
1548       {
1549         const char *preinc = targetcm.c_preinclude ();
1550         if (preinc && cpp_push_default_include (parse_in, preinc))
1551           return;
1552       }
1553     }
```

and pseudo-filenames `"<built-in>"` and `"<command-line>"` are added in `c_finish_options` there also.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013318/what-is-built-in-in-c-preprocessor-output) answer your first part?

Comment: @Zoso No, it doesn't. At least for gcc.

Comment: Why not? It clearly describes what `<built-in>` and `<command-line>` mean. Perhaps the `cpp` reference is not clear to you? That's the preprocessor and is what `gcc` invokes so it does describe `gcc` behaviour. Run `gcc -E -dM main.c` if you don't want to run `cpp` directly.

Comment: `from where /usr/include/stdc-predef.h is taken?` What do you mean "from where"? The file is taken from your hard drive.

Comment: @kaylum In case of `<built-in>` appearance I can understand its presence among aforesaid lines. It is used for adding predefined macros I guess. What about `<command-line>` if it is used for adding macros from command-line why it is used three times instead of one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with an empty header.

```
$ touch foo.h
```

You are already aware of the numbers in the output of the preprocessor, so won't re-iterate. Coming to `<built-in>`, it is the list of the predefined macros. Using the [preprocessor documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp)

> -dM Instead of the normal output, generate a list of #define
> directives for all the macros defined during the
> execution of the preprocessor, including predefined
> macros.  This gives you a way of finding out what is
> predefined in your version of the preprocessor.  Assuming
> you have no file foo.h, the command
>
> ```
> touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h
> ```
>
> shows all the predefined macros.

So, doing that should give all the predefined macros and their expanions as:

```
#define __SSP_STRONG__ 3
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT32X_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
:
```

To see how `<command-line>` is expanded, pass in a command-line define using the `-DX=Y` syntax

```
$ gcc -E -DDBG=1 -dN foo.h|grep 'command-line' -A 1 -B 1
#define __DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT__
# 1 "<command-line>"
#define DBG
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           #define __STDC_ISO_10646__
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "foo.h"
```

`DBG` shows up under the `<command-line>` set

As for `"/usr/include/stdc-predef.h"`, well that's the file that contains some of those pred-defined macros. e.g on my system:

```
#ifdef __GCC_IEC_559
# if __GCC_IEC_559 > 0
#  define __STDC_IEC_559__              1
# endif
```

which matches with the pre-processor output:

```
$ gcc -E foo.h -dM|grep __STDC_IEC_559__
#define __STDC_IEC_559__ 1
```

You can always use the `cpp` binary for just doing the pre-processing part instead of using `gcc -E`.

A lot more is actually explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150378/1851678) answer.

Comment: I found that `gcc -E -nostdinc foo.h` disables using `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h` also.

Comment: Do you know how to get a list of predefined "command-line" parameters where on the line 31 locates the file "stdc-predef.h"?

Comment: @edem I too am not sure of that. Interestingly clang doesn't have any such thing.

Comment: For the file /usr/include/stdc-predef.h see the updated question.